# Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseGoogleServices'. Failed to delete: ...../values.xml

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I have a React Native project. I'm in the process of building the release build for android (I had no issues with iOS) on macOS. I've been following this guide: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android. When I run `./gradlew assembleRelease`, I get the following error:

```
:app:processReleaseGoogleServices
Parsing json file: /Users/robavery/repositories/ourdailystrength_app/android/app/google-services.json
:app:processReleaseGoogleServices FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseGoogleServices'.
> Failed to delete: /Users/robavery/repositories/ourdailystrength_app/android/app/build/generated/res/google-services/release/values/values.xml

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 47s
```

I've cleaned and get the same error when I try and clean my project (no matter if I clean through Android Studio, `./gradlew clean`, or `npm run clean:android`).

I tried running `sudo ./gradlew assembleRelease`, but then I just get this error:

```
> Task :app:processReleaseGoogleServices
Parsing json file: /Users/robavery/repositories/ourdailystrength_app/android/app/google-services.json


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' property '$1' during up-to-date check.
> Failed to create MD5 hash for file '/Users/robavery/repositories/ourdailystrength_app/.buckd/sock' as it does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
```

Though, I'd rather be able to run this as an user instead of sudo.

What is causing this error? How do I get around this and successfully do a gradle build for release without having to use sudo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is permissions this is not super safe but should work

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /Users/robavery/repositories/ourdailystrength_app
```

just using `chmod` to modify persions to `777` which is an alias for all groups, all permissions, `-R` flag runs it recursively so you hit every file in the directory.

If that doesn't work then maybe try [clearing your project cache](https://gist.github.com/jarretmoses/c2e4786fd342b3444f3bc6beff32098d)

Comment: That must have been my initial issue because after doing that, it's giving me the same issue mentioned above when I run it with sudo.

Comment: alright I would definitely try clearing your cache then